# Is Bounded Waiting satisfied for this 2 process Solution?

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization, deadlocks

This is my new post linked with my previous post.

[Is bounded waiting satisfied in the 2 Process Solution?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/is-bounded-waiting-satisfied-in-the-2-process-solution/67282)

---

The answer in that post was very useful and cleared many concepts, but I just want to apply that answer for this example, that how BW works here .

Especially, I want to know this definition works for this example.

> Define $k$-bounded waiting for a given mutual exclusion algorithm to
>   mean that if $D_A^j \to D_B^l$ then $CS_A^{j} \to CS_B^{l+k}$.

---

Here, the Question comes

> What can be said bout the Bounded Waiting of this 2 process solution"

**<------- P1 ------->**

```
While(True)
{
    acquire(lock1)
    acquire(lock2)
        withdraw(from, amount)
        deposit(to, amount)
    release(lock2)
    release(lock1)
}
```

**<-------- P2 -------->**

```
While(True)
{
    acquire(lock1)
    acquire(lock2)
        withdraw(from, amount)
        deposit(to, amount)
    release(lock2)
    release(lock1)
}
```

Comment: Can you articulate a more specific question than "What can be said about..."?  What specifically are you unsure/confused about?  Have you tried applying the definition to that example, and what did you come up with and where specifically did you get stuck/confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, I treat the first two statements `acquire(lock1) acquire(lock2)` as "trying", the middle two statements `withdraw(from, amount) deposit(to, amount)` as the "critical section", and the last two statements `release(lock2) release(lock1)` as "exiting".

This algorithm does not satisfy the bounded waiting property. Consider the following execution: $P_1$ and $P_2$ simultaneously execute `acquire(lock1)` and $P_1$ wins. $P_1$ acquires `lock2` successfully, enters the critical section, and then exit by releasing locks. Now, $P_1$ and $P_2$ contend on `acquire(lock1)` again and $P_1$ wins again .... In this way, $P_2$ is actually starved.

Comment: why P1 is given more priority, there is nothing mentioned about priority right?

Comment: @PavanKumarMunnam I am *constructing* an execution which violates the bounded waiting property. I am free to schedule processes as I will.

Comment: if i replace the lock by P and V operations where P makes the processes goes into the block and V operation which wakes up the process from sleep , does that force P1 process to wake up P2 and allow that execution, is Bounded waiting satisfied in that case?

Comment: @PavanKumarMunnam You are talking about a single individual detailed implementation. However, you should focus on the *worst-case* scenario.  In addition, being woken up does not mean $P_2$ immediately holds the lock. It has to compete with $P_1$ which is also trying to acquire the same lock. The worst case here is to let $P_1$ always win.

Comment: @PavanKumarMunnam: Design of any solution to Critical-Section Problem should be done which is free from or irrespective of speed and number of  processors and priority of processes.

Comment: what about starvation as there is no bounded waiting so there will be starvation right?

Comment: @PavanKumarMunnam Yes. Starvation is possible, as illustrated in the execution constructed in this answer.

Comment: please give your reviews on this http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67434/starvation-is-possible-or-not

Comment: @hengxin Thanks for the reason!! In my previous question, I asked the same thing where P2 starved, then how BW was satisfied there ?