# Starvation is possible or not?

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization

let S and Q to be initialized to 1

```
process p0:          process p1:

wait(S);             wait(Q);
wait(Q);             wait(S); 

..                    ..
..                    ..
Signal(S);           Signal(Q);
Signal(Q);           Signal(S);
```

I know there is a deadlock , where both the process will be going into the sleep , so what about starvation and bounded waiting?

My approach:

as only p0 can be executed any number of times i think there will be starvation and no bounded waiting.But answer is given that there is **No Starvation**.

Comment: I don't understand why "the answer" is "no starvation". Note that starvation freedom implies deadlock freedom. Since it suffers from deadlocks, it must also suffer from starvations.

Comment: @hengxin you meant to say that if there is deadlock then that implies starvation?

Comment: No starvation $\implies$ No deadlock. So deadlock $\implies$ starvation.

Comment: i was thinking this way http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67406/does-deadlock-imply-starvation/67415#67415

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is wrong**.

**Deadlock** implies **starvation**, and the given code suffers from deadlock, here's how.

Say `p0` executes `wait(S);` and then p1 executes `wait(Q);`. Now both the `semaphores` `S` and `Q` have `value = 0`.Now `p0` will keep on waiting due to statement `wait(Q);` and `p1` will keep on waiting due to statement `wait(S);`.

Freedom from starvation means that:

> if a thread tries to acquire a lock , it will eventually succeed.

This does not happen here, so the answer is wrong.